# Анимация на чистом JavaScript или jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, анимация, css-animation

```css
#block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  animation: block 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes block {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    background-color: red;
  }
  50% {
    left: calc(100% - 100px);
    background-color: green;
  }
  500% {
    left: 0;
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="block"></div>
```

Можно ли такую анимацию сделать на чистом JavaScript или jQuery?

Comment: А зачем? На css лучше.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript

```js
var block = document.querySelector('#block');
var player = block.animate([{
    left: "0",
    backgroundColor: "red"
  },
  {
    left: "calc(100% - 100px)",
    backgroundColor: "green"
  }
], {
  duration: 1500,
  iterations: Infinity,
  direction: 'alternate',
  easing: "linear"
});
```

```css
#block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="block"></div>
```

jQuery

```js
(function animation() {
  $("#block")
    .animate({
      left: '100%',
      'margin-left': '-100px',
      backgroundColor: "green"
    }, 1500)
    .animate({
      left: '0',
      'margin-left': '0px',
      backgroundColor: "red"
    }, 1500, animation)
}());
```

```css
#block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="block"></div>
```

Comment: `'margin-left': '0px', backgroundColor: "red"` - копипаст какой-то xD

Comment: У пикселей кавычки одинарные, у цвета - двойные, отступ через дефис, цвет с большой буквой, хотя jQuery оба способа понимает и можно написать одинаково. Как-будто из разных мест скопипащено.